# to / at / on certain level / point / degree

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-construction

I would like to say

> I have become acclimatized to medical terminology to / at / on certain
>   level/ point /degree after having worked for years with health workers.

What I try to say is that I have limited knowledge, not an expert level but it is kind of more than average or layman.

Which ways would be correct to say?

Comment: I don't see why you can't omit all the [to / at / on certain level/ point /degree] entirely. "I have become acclimatized to medical terminology after having worked for years with health workers." This does not claim any particular expertise, but gets across that it is more than the layman would know.

Comment: @Weather Vane I see your point and you are right. However, phrases such as " to a degree" is still useful to soften the tone of a sentence in order to imply "there could be more to learn even on the layman level because I recognize it is a broad subject"

Comment: Are you asking about "to/at/on" or "level/point/degree"? Or both? If you are asking about both, then you are asking us to choose from 9 combinations. That is a lot. Can you omit the ones you feel are least likely to be correct, please.

Comment: In that case the simpler "I have some familiarity with medical terminology after working for years in the health industry" will imply that it is extensive but incomplete.